# How to fill a cell with database tables

Tags: html, sql

I was wondering how you can fill a whole column of a table from a database table? using HTML and SQL? I am using Toad for Oracle and using MySQL as a compiler. I just want to fill a column using a loop but don't know how to do it?

if I had a table like :

```
Table1
------
  Y
  N
  Y
```

Here is the procedure code:

```
procedure proc1

is

begin 


HTP.P('

<HTML>
<BODY>

<b> <font size="4" color=black>Status Log</font> </b>
<table bgcolor="black" width=1020 align="center" border="0"  cellspacing="1" class="sortable"><THEAD><tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">


');



htp.p('

<th width=30 align=left><font size="2">Phase</font></th>

        <td>  </td>

<th width=50 align=left><font size="2">State</font></th>

        <td>  </td>

<th width=414 align=left><font size="2">CHG</font></th>

        <td>  </td>

<th width=30 align=left><font size="2">Changes</font></th>

        <td>  </td>

<th width=180 align=left><font size="2">Completed</font></th>

        <td>  </td>

</table>

</BODY>
</HTML>

');

end proc1;
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?  http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0601__System-Packages/DisplayrecordsinaHTMLtable.htm

Comment: Thank you, it is a good reference and has given me a start.